# Do pyqt4 tooltips now work on Mac OS?

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm developing a cross-platform software, I wanted to write code that is platform independent. Small issue, I've seen a lot of people reporting that tooltips using pyqt4 do not work on Mac. Is this resolved now?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
QtGui.qApp = app

pointListBox = QtGui.QTreeWidget()

header=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(["Tree","First","secondo"])
pointListBox.setHeaderItem(header)

root = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(pointListBox, ["root"])
A = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(root, ["A"])
barA = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(A, ["bar", "i", "ii"])
bazA = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(A, ["baz", "a", "b"])
barA.setToolTip(0,"tooltip working")
bazA.setToolTip(0,"tooltip working")


pointListBox.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The tooltips in the above program work on Ubuntu and Windows. Does it on Mac OS?

Comment: Qt4 is legacy code (support ended 19th Dec 2015). So if tooltips on OSX are still broken in Qt-4.8.7, there is now no chance of them ever being fixed. Qt5 also had some tooltip bugs on OSX, but those seem to have been fixed in Qt-5.5.1.